# Python send mtom message

Tags: python, soap, mtom

How do I send an mtom message in python? I have tried using the `requests` library but I am getting an error from the server. The workflow is HTTP headers with a SOAP envelope and a binary attachment. I am using an MTOM template file which is structured as follows:

```
 Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary=boundary1234567890; type="application/xop+xml";
 start="<0.urn:uuid:1FACEDB95C3509148F1570480012346@w3.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 SOAPAction: "soap-action"
 
 --boundary1234567890
 Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:1FACEDB95C3509148F1570480012346@w3.org>

 set soap envelope here
 
 --boundary1234567890
 Content-Type: application/zip
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-ID: <1.urn:uuid:1FACEDB95C3509148F1570480012347@w3.org>

 set binary attachment here
```

I then send the message with the python `requests` library as follows:

```
import requests
data = open(template, 'rb').read()
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={})
```

However, I am getting an error from the server saying that my request was not able to be processed. I am probably doing something wrong, but I do not know how to send an MTOM message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have success? Could you share your results?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only real support for MTOM
is currently in Java and C#.You can use Axis2/C which I believe supports MTOM and
put a Python wrapper around it.